# Syntax Error for around LIMIT

Tags: mysql, limit

I'm working on a training course for PHP and I think the mysql syntax is outdated. This is the function

```
function get_subject_by_id($subject_id) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    $query .= "WHERE id=" . $subject_id ." ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($result_set);
    if ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
        return $subject;
    } else { 
            return NULL;
    }
}
```

and I'm getting back this error:
Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help from someone who knows what might have changed in the syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paste your final $query here.

Comment: <?php 
 if(isset($_GET['subj'])) {
   $sel_subj = $_GET['subj'];
   $sel_page = "";
 } elseif (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $sel_subj = "";
   $sel_page = $_GET['page'];
 } else {
   $sel_subj = "";
   $sel_page = "";
 }
 $sel_subject = get_subject_by_id($sel_subj);
?>

Comment: Then lower down 

                <td id="page">
                 <h2> <?php echo $sel_subject['menu_name']; ?></h2> 
                    <br />
                    <?php echo $sel_page; ?> <br />                           
                </td>

Comment: No, no, dude, just add `echo $query;` after `$query .= "LIMIT 1";` and paste output in your question ;)

Comment: Sorry, like I said still really new to this. When I added echo $query under the limit 1 line, I get this output. Thanks for any insight you have on it:  

SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id= LIMIT 1Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: Your `$subject_id` is empty and query fails, it is normal. you have to pass ID by argument something like `get_subject_by_id(3);`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I feel like an idiot. When the page was loading in the lesson we had already given it a subject_id and so I was trying to load the page just from scratch without that. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM subjects
          WHERE id = $subject_id 
          LIMIT 1";
```

Query fails because $subject_id is empty.

```
SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE id= LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Off-topic but cleaner, however it introduces superfluous whitespace.

Comment: I use inline if there isn't any JOIN and so on, I am just sending message to author that he can write it like this, without appending to string with each line ;)

Comment: The other query's in this lesson I'm going through are written like this. I think they are trying to show different ways to write code. If it helps I did swap out the syntax to this form and go the same error.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't matter how it is written, it won't work anyway, because $subject_id is empty, adding any number will work but it will probably return empty set. I don't know database structure or what is what so you are on your own :)

Comment: You actually helped me zero in on it in the main question area. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

apparently the `$subject_id` is causing the trouble, check if the value is passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Two wild guesses:

- You did not quote / escape `$subject_id` which contains a string or something non-integer (such as `FALSE`, `NULL` or the empty string).
  Even if this is not the cause, it makes your script vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection).
- You are using a Mac for coding and have erroneously inserted a non-breakable space